# Curl command to NSURLRequest Swift

Tags: ios, swift, curl, nsmutableurlrequest

I was converting the following curl command:

`curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: Bearer 34kjsfhjbdjkh.jdhfds334jdshfksfs.kkjkjdsakjsd"  -d "current_pwd=oldpassword&new_pwd1=newpassword&new_pwd2=newpassword" localhost:3000/updateDetails`

into a `NSURLRequest`:

```
 func updatePassword(passwordInfo : NSDictionary){
    let urlString = generateURLString("/updateDetails")

    if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
        let currPwd = passwordInfo["currPwd"] as! String
        let nPwd1 = passwordInfo["newPwd1"] as! String
        let nPwd2 = passwordInfo["newPwd2"] as! String

        var stringPost = "current_pwd=" + currPwd
        stringPost += "&new_pwd1=" + nPwd1
        stringPost += "&new_pwd2=" + nPwd2

        let data = stringPost.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

        request.HTTPMethod = "PUT"
        request.addValue("Bearer " + getSessionToken(), forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.HTTPBody=data

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
            (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                    if let responseData = data {
                        let json = JSON(data: responseData)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

The curl command works perfectly fine. 
I'm using node.js express framework for running the server.

```
var currentPwd = req.body.current_pwd;
var newPwd1 = req.body.new_pwd1;
var newPwd2 = req.body.new_pwd2;
```

The password value is received on the server when sent through the curl command. When the request is sent through iOS, the newPwd1 value or any of the three is undefined. Any idea why? Am I missing something?

**Update**:
Express 4 configuration for body parsing is as follows:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

**Update 2**:
This seems to be weird. When I tried to print the log for the request body using a  curl command:  the request body seems to be valid

```
{ current_pwd: 'oldPwd',
  new_pwd1: 'newPwd',
  new_pwd2: 'newPwd' }
```

When the log is printed out for the request body using iOS NSURLRequest I get an empty body:
{}

Comment: if you do a `print("stringPost is \(stringPost)")` right before you create your NSMutableURLRequest, does stringPost have the values you expect?

Comment: Yes. The string to be posted is the same as in the curl command

Comment: What else appears in the `req` structure on the node.js express side when the `PUT` is received?  Anything valid and expected?

Comment: Updated my question with the request body for curl command and ios request

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the value for header field 'Content-type'.

```
request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")
```

That fixed it.